# Is Chow Liu's scoring algorithm to have at most one root node?

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes, bayesian-network

I am told that Chow Liu's algorithm can have at most one root node. In the fisr place what does it mean? I am wondering how I can apply Chow Liu's scoring function for more than one root node to do a bayesian strucral learning.

Answer (score 3):

It means that there will be one root and any node(except the root) has only one parent(except the class).

I don't think you need to break some connections to make several trees since adding one more connectin will increase the likelihood a bit given the data D. In the paper Chow Liu proved that CL the procedure finds the tree(maximum weighted spanning tree) that maximizes the likelihood given the data D.

Comment: But, in general, Bayesian network allows any DAG, which allows two parents for a single node. So, these trees are just approximations (or) can only create Bayesian trees (not Bayesian graphs).? Is it true?